# En $request de PHP Nginx no pasa parámetros (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, url, nginx, parametros

Utilizo PHP, Nginx, Laravel 9. Estoy configurando el webhook de meta / facebook para recibir notificaciones de mensajes de whatsapp vía webhook. Esta es la ruta:

```
Route::get('/whatsapp-webhook', [ChatController::class, 'verifyWebhook']);
```

Y función en el controlador ChatController:

```
public function verifyWebhook(Request $request)
{
    try {
        $mode = $request->input('hub_mode');
        $token = $request->input('hub_challenge');
        $challenge = $request->input('hub_verify_token');

        if ($mode && $token) {
            if ($mode === 'subscribe' && $token == config('app.whatsapp.amparo_token')) {
                return response($challenge, 200)->header('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
            }
        }

        throw ValidationException::withMessages(['info' => 'Petición inválida']);

    } catch (Throwable $th) {
        return Response::json([
            'success' => false,
            'data' => $th->getMessage(),
        ], 500);
    }
}
```

Esta validación le devuelve un 200 a facebook y funciona perfecto en modo prueba con ngrok

```
ngrok http 8000
```

Toma los datos y valida la url en la plataforma de Meta. Pero cuando salgo de ngrok ese $request ya no llega igual. En producción con mi dominio, algo está cambiando como se interpreta ese $request. No sé si es PHP, Laravel o alguna otra cosa.

UPDATE: Corregí el error que me comentaron de tener intercambiados challenge y token pero sigue fallando la validación en META, agregué un Log antes del try para ver como llega el $request en producción:

```
    Log::warning('Request', [
        'challenge' => $request->input('hub_challenge'),
        'token' => $request->input('hub_verify_token'),
        'mode' => $request->input('hub_mode'),
    ]);
```

Y el resultado es este:

```
Request {"challenge":null,"token":null,"mode":null}
```

Y con ngrok:

```
Request {"challenge":"553847107","token":"EAARHIQChSfIBAJj8wlfaZAZCWqULfoSAZDZD","mode":"subscribe"}
```

Con ngrok el $request trae los datos bien pero en producción llegan null.

UPDATE 2: Agregué el $request->all() en el log y llega completamente vacío.

```
    Log::warning('Request', [
        'all' => $request->all(),
        'challenge' => $request->input('hub_challenge'),
        'token' => $request->input('hub_verify_token'),
        'mode' => $request->input('hub_mode'),
    ]);
```

Resultado:

```
Request {"all":[],"challenge":null,"token":null,"mode":null}
```

UPDATE 3: He intentado enviando el request con Postman y también llega completamente vacío. O sea que no habría problema con META ni con mi controller, por alguna razón en el medio se rompe.

[image: configuración en Postman y resultado]

Comment: Estás usando el protocolo https en produccion? No sé ese servicio, pero en las apis de facebook suelen se estrictos con eso

Comment: Si, es https mi dominio. https://amparosrl.com.ar

Comment: Si haces `Log::warning('Request', $request->all());` que te muestra? No hay nada mas en el request?

Comment: Si, llega vacío, voy a intentar con Postman enviar los datos y actualizo de nuevo.

Comment: En el update 4 `GET /whatsapp-webhook? hub.mode=subscribe&hub.challenge=456905420&hub.verify_token=EAARHIQChSfIBAJj8wlfaZAZCWqULfoSAZDZD` se ve que hay parametros como query strings. Por un lado la clave es distinta a la que estas queriendo obtener `hub.mode` vs `hub_mode`. Por otro, estas queriendo obtener el valor de un input `$request->input('hub_mode')` pero es una peticion GET, por lo que te sugiero que pruebes con `$request->query('hub.mode')`

Comment: O `$request->getQueryString()` a ver si los podes obtener asi

Comment: Hice un update 5 del post, el punto (.) php lo transforma en guión bajo (_), probando con ngrok hace la transformación y lo lee bien, igual he probado de las dos formas, con punto y guion bajo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pude encontrar la solución, el problema era Nginx, resulta que la instalación básica bloquea parámetros de PHP, envía las url de estas peticiones pero sin parámetros, se soluciona agregando $args en el location en la configuración de Nginx, de esta forma:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /www/index.php?$args;
```

Answer (score 0):

Según veo en el código en la siguiente validación `$mode === 'subscribe' && $token == config('app.whatsapp.amparo_token')`, estas validando el `hub_challenge`, y devolviendo el `verify_token` este debe ser a la inversa debes validar el `verify_token` y de devolver el `hub_challenge`. ya que el verify_token en es el que configuras al momento de registrar el webhook en META, y este deber coincidir con el que tienes en el config de tu app. como lo estas haciendo ahora siempre va lanzar la excepción ya que no pasa esa validación.

Nota: La Raiz del problema se encuentra en esta asignación

```
$token = $request->input('hub_challenge');
$challenge = $request->input('hub_verify_token');
```

Comment: Gracias, es cierto, error de tanto hacer y dehacer, ya lo arreglé pero sigue fallando porque las variables en el $request llegan null, actualizo el post para comentarlo.

Comment: podrías sacar todo el $request->all() en un log, también podrías pobrar desde postman apuntando al endpoint en el dominio real y ver si llega la data correctamente